# Advice on modeling behaviors/concepts not commonly thought to be persisted

Tags: rest

I am looking for advice and experience related to the best way to REST-ify behaviors/concepts that are not "commonly persisted" - in other words, resource-ifying transformative or side-effect behaviors.

First, let me say that I know there's no complete test for REST-ful-ness - and actually I don't care.  I find the CRUD-over-the-Web notion of REST very intuitive and it works well on most of the data I'm providing access to.  At the same time, I am not worried about straying from anyones bible on how to perfectly REST-ify something.  I'm in search of whatever the best compromise between practical and REST-intuitive is for the cases that don't fit so well.  Clearly, consistency is the main goal, but intuitive-ness helps ensure that.

Given that, let me dive into the details of what I'm after.

Since REST is inherently resource-oriented, it is easy to model things commonly persisted - what is less clear is how to model behaviors/concepts that are not commonly persisted, especially those which have side effects or are purely transformational.

For example, take a stackoverflow.com question.  It can be Created, Updated, Read, and Deleted.  Everyone can relate to that and it all makes sense under REST.

But now consider something like a translation - for example, I want to build a REST API for my service that translates an English sentence to Spanish.

There are at least two ways to address the translation scenario.  I could:

- Look at a translation invocation as the creation of a "translation instance" (which doesn't happen to be persisted, but could be), in which case a POST /Translation (i.e., a create) actually makes a lot of sense.  This is particularly the case if the translation service requires the URL of something to be translated (since the contents of that URL can change over time).
- Look at translation as really the act of querying a larger dictionary of known answers, in which case a GET /Translation (i.e., a read) might be more appropriate.  This is especially tempting if the translation service requires just the text of the sentence to be translated.  Noone would expect the translation of a static sentence to change over time.  You could also argue that it could be cacheable, which GET would lend itself towards.

This same dilemma can crop up for other actions which primarily have side effects (e.g., sending an SMS or an e-mail) and are less commonly associated with persistence of the data.

My approach thus far has been to essentially "Order"-ify these cases, that is looking at everything as though one was placing an order.  More generally, I think this is just converting verbs (translate) into nouns (translation order), which would seem to be one way of REST-ifying such things.

Can anyone share a better, more intuitive, way to approach the modeling of actions/behaviors that are not commonly assumed to be persisted?

Answer (score 2):

The "Would it hurt to do more than once?"-test perhaps?

In your examples - what would happen if you are asked to translate the same text twice? Not really much. Sending an sms twice is likely to be a bad thing though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I agree that's a helpful test at times.  However, as I mention, if I'm passing in a URL to a web page to translate, then yes - doing it twice could produce different results (e.g., the page was changed in between times I made the request), so I guess it depends on the details of the service.

Comment: Producing a different result is not necessarily a reason against using GET - after all, GET on the changed page would do that too.  That's why we have Last-Modified and Expires.  The GET-or-not-GET debate is more about side-effects than reproducability per se

Answer (score 1):

The two options you describe are valid options and you have already highlighted scenarios when one is better than the other.  The only other option I would suggest which is use POST with a "processing resource".  e.g.

```
POST /translator?from=en&to=fr
Content-Type: text/plain
Body: The sentence to be translated
=>
200 OK
La phrase à traduire
```

One nice thing about "processing resources" is that they may or may not have persistent side effects.  Obviously the disadvantage is that intermediaries can't cache the response.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think this is akin to the noun-ification of verbs like translate, so I agree it's in line with the first option I presented.  And I agree with you about the disadvantage.

Comment: @Kelly The distinction in my head is that POST /Translations returns a 201 Created and a Location header that has an URL to a new resource that contains the result of the translation. That new resource may only exist temporarily, but is accessed by a secondary GET.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but I guess that seems less attractive to me than the first bullet I suggested above where I (not so directly) implied that the POST /Translations would return the result (no secondary GET required).  If a secondary GET is required, I think it would violate the statelessness aspect of the model, unless I persisted the answer temporarily. (which may be what you're suggesting).  Thanks again.

Comment: @Kelly The option where a new resource is created is useful for operations that may take a long time.  In your case this "processing resource" option where the result is returned immediately from the POST is definitely a better option.  I just prefer to call resources like that "Translator" rather than "translation" or "translations" as it seems more obvious in my head that I am going to get a translated response back.